# Select two columns from two different table with multiple join[Mysql]

Tags: mysql

I have four tables are `users(id,name)`, `roles(id,name)`, `members(project_id,user_id,id)`, and `member_roles(member_id, role_id)`. So how can I select users.name and roles.name from this tables simultaneously(project_id is the condition to select exactly the names what we need)?. I can select users.name and roles.name separately but when I connect two queries, my code was failed. This is the query to get users.name

```
select users.name from users
inner join members on members.user_id = users.id
where project_id = 1
```

and here is the query to get roles.name

```
select roles.name from roles
inner join member_roles on member_roles.role_id = roles.id
join members on members.id = member_roles.member_id
where project_id = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Also, to avoid ambiguity, supply an *Alias* on column `Name`.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT 
        u.Name AS member_name,
        r.Name AS role_name
FROM    users u
        INNER JOIN members m 
            ON u.id = m.user_id
        INNER JOIN member_roles mr
            ON m.id = mr.member_id
        INNER JOIN roles r
            ON r.id = mr.role_id
WHERE   m.project_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you connect 2 queries? How about something like this:

```
select u.name as user_name, r.name as role_name from users u join members m on m.user_id = u.id join member_roles mr on mr.member_id = m.id join roles r on r.id = mr.role_id where m.project_id = 1;
```